# Is it safe to drink tap water in Germany?

Tags: germany, munich, tap-water, bavaria

I just arrived in Germany for the 4th time. I made tea in break of the work meeting, and at the very end of it, I found small solid pieces... I thought that the cup was too old and maybe was starting to lose its "material". A guy told me that this because of the water being "too heavy" here in Germany, and he doesn't drink it, but filters the water through a machine, and then drinks it.

During my first trip, I asked if it is OK to drink tap water in my hotel, and they said yes, but we don't drink it, we buy mineral water from the market. And from all the people I have asked here, this is what I get as an answer, more or less.

My mother told me that the water in Germany is not drinkable, because it has too much iron. I think here they call it kalk, which seems to be some metal in any case.

The knowledge of my mother is likely to be outdated, and while searching the Internet, I see that the situation has changed across the years, and that now it's safe to drink tap water, which contradicts what people say in real life. I am very confused.

So, is it safe to drink tap water in Germany? Nobody gives a boolean answer which makes me worry! If area matters, we travel in Munich and nearby towns, all parts of Bavaria.

Comment: I’ve been drinking German tap water for dozens of years and am still alive.

Comment: I searched for a duplicate with `Germany` as the key word, since there are many questions of the style: "Is it safe to drink tap water in <country>?". Thanks @chirlu.

Comment: I'll use an example. at my work I don't drink the tap water because of all the kalk. my work is next to a place where they make concrete so it is safe to use, but there is too much kalk in the water. About 5 miles away is where I live and the water tastes fine there. So it also depends on where your going to be staying.

Comment: @OmamArmy so it would be a good idea to ask the hotels, thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tap water is Germany's most tested food. It is 100% safe to drink. Water is tested frequently and the results can be read online or in your local newspaper.

Having said that, in places where the tap water is from springs it can be very hard indeed. This deposits limescale (calcium carbonate or "Kalk") in household devices if you don't soften it. The limescale can crumble into your water if the pipes are old. It is harmless to humans, but a nuisance.

This business of drinking bottled water is just a mode, and you don't need to. But you might prefer the taste, that's up to you.

Comment: I am OK with the taste. So, you are saying, that is safe not to soften it, thanks!